# ios-sending email from an ipad application

Tags: html, ios

i am trying to send an email from my own app.
i want images inline along with the text in the body of the mail.
if i am using the HTML image tag the image is coming in my side but not visible in receiver side.
if i add my images as attachment then i am able to see my images twice one as attachment and other as inline.
this works fine in the receiver side. but the problem is i am seeing the images twice.
i want those images to be appeared only once that too in the body not as attachments.

Comment: This depends on how you're attaching the images and referring to them in the html.

Comment: i dint refer anything in the HTML. just gave the bundle path